# How Would I Center Text In This DIV?

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

I have a small offline website(uploaded @ http://razorcloud.cz.cc/ for this)with a header which contains a logo, a navigation bar, and a notification bar. I seem to have them all lined up properly and how I'd like. The downside, however, is that now the text inside of the notification bar(header-alert) is not centered correctly.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
            <img style="float: left; padding-left: 20px" src="images/versace-logo.bmp" width="230" height="120" />
            <div class="bottom-header">
                <div class="navigation-bar" style="margin-top: 90px">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-container dropdown-shadow">
                                <ul class="dropdown-column">
                                    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Video</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:left"></div>
            <div class="header-alert">
                This website is still under development!
            </div>
        </header>
```

CSS:

```
.header
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: "GillSansStdRegular";
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom-header
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigation-bar
{
    clear: right;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header-alert
{
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-family: "GillSansStdLightRegular";
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have tried multiple attempts to fix it, such as the display and margin attributes, but I seem unable to find a solution to does not include modifying the exact layout I currently have. It may be something simple though that is above my head. I'm not looking for any things like adding spaces to even it out.

Comment: can you tell which element you want to center

Comment: The one with the "header-alert" tag.

Comment: "header-alert" tag is already centerd

Comment: Look at the website. It's not exactly in the center like it should be.

Comment: am really confused about this question

Comment: @user1953522 it is because of that home and video button make there top and bottom margin zero than tell me

Comment: That causes the menu to raise all the way to the top of the page. I have marked an answer as working though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height: 40px;` in `.navigation-bar`

Comment: This doesn't work exactly how I'd like. As told in the original question, I've tried this and it brings down the notification bar much too far. Changing the margin-top doesn't work making this useless.

Comment: Updated my answer check now

Comment: While your exact answer didn't work, I made the height equal to 0 and changed the independent DIV to "clear: both" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

change that one line before your hearder-alert from  "clear:left" to "clear:both"

```
<div style="clear:left"></div>
            <div class="header-alert">
```

to

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div class="header-alert">
```

And remove margin-top: 15px; for .header-alert

Comment: That centers the text, but pushes the DIV down. Using a combination of this and creating/setting the height of .navigation-bar to 0 works.

Comment: As a suggested edit above , you can remove margin-top u set to push it back up.

Comment: Yes, that pushes it up just a bit, but not all the way to the spot before changing that and the clear attribute to both.

Answer (score 0):

The `.navigation-bar` is pushing the `.header-alert` away, just add `position: absolute;` in `.navigation-bar` and set the spacing from the right side with `right: 10px;` (for example).

You can also remove `float:right;` from `.navigation-bar`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="images/versace-logo.bmp" width="230" height="120" />
</div>
        <div class="bottom-header">
            <div class="navigation-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-container dropdown-shadow">
                            <ul class="dropdown-column">
                                <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Video</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-alert">
            This website is still under development!
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.header
{
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    font-family: "GillSansStdRegular";
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.img {
    float: left; padding-left: 20px; position: relative;

}

.bottom-header
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

}

.navigation-bar
{
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    color: white;
}

.header-alert
{
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-family: "GillSansStdLightRegular";
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

`Check this link:` [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tsurendra/846z22c9/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how navigation-bar is overextending itself downwards to the point that it affects header-alert. You also used margins in conjunction with a float to position it. My corrections below are based on the navmenu of a recent website I coded for a client located at http://calaverasfamilydentistry.net/

Remove or comment out the following:

```
.bottom-header {
    /*display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;*/
}
```

And add or overwrite the following (you can adjusted the bottom and right properties but I've taken the liberty of brute-forcing my way to match your original position.)

```
.navigation-bar {
    bottom: 0.75em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.65em;
}
```

You can also remove or comment out the following as its not really needed and might just get in the way.

```
.navigation-bar {
    /*clear: right;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;*/
}
```